# Use "npm install -name-" removes "npm link" dirs from node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-link

I have my development package. I did "npm link" for it.
Now I go to another project and set up it here "npm link **my**".
Everything is good at this stage.

**npm install node-fetch**
But if I need to install something else, then after installation, my first project (link to **my**) disappears from node_modules.

And I have to do the installation again.
**npm link my**

Why is this happening? It is very uncomfortable.

npm 8.11.0 / Win10

This has happened many times and needs to be reinstalled each time.